# No mobs are spawning in my Mob Farm (in the Mushroom Island biome)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a problem with my mob farm spawning room (16x16) and it's that there's no mobs spawning in it.
I'm playing single player Minecraft 1.10 on hard difficulty and I have built it in a Mushroom Island so there's no other place for the mobs to spawn and It's mention that it is 30 blocks high.

What do you think is the problem?

Some pics:

Spawn Room
[image: Spawn Room]

The Roof

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have built it in a Mushroom Island

No mobs other than mooshrooms spawn naturally in mushroom island biomes. Unfortunately, you will need to rebuild the farm in another biome for mobs to be able to spawn.

Here's a test I did, showing that no mobs spawn in mushroom island biome:

[image: Quick mob spawning test]

Comment: But I have seen creepers here.

Comment: @AmirHB Likely that they spawned outside of the island biome and wandered in.

Comment: I saw them spawn on the grass dirt. I guess mobs' problem is with mycelium dirt not the whole mushroom island biome!

Comment: @AmirHB I believe mobs problem is with the whole mushroom island biome. If there's grass, then that's most likely outside of the mushroom island biome. I'll try testing it, though.

Comment: @AmirHB [Test results](http://i.imgur.com/DlfYSK9.png) show that no mobs appear to spawn in the mushroom island biome.

Comment: Well, That's unfortunate but also helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: @coporfusion Just one more question! Can I Build it in the middle of the ocean? :/

Comment: @AmirHB Yep, mobs can spawn in ocean biomes.

Answer (score -1):

No mobs will spawn in Mushroom islands. It is considered the safest place in Minecraft. So u can build your mob but in another biome.

Comment: The mushroom biome is unique in that only one mob spawns - the mooshroom. (that red cow with mushrooms on it)

Comment: Ya. What u said is correct. :D